# Gatsby/Netlify project not in root of git repo

Tags: git, gatsby, netlify

Note for an XY-problem discussion of whether the premise of the question is a bad idea, please see here: [Git repo containing BackEnd and FrontEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277572/git-repo-containing-backend-and-frontend)

---

My git repo looks like this:

```
root
|
|- .git\
|
|- JSFrontEnd\
|             |- package.json
|             |- tsconfig.json
|             |- .cache\
|             |- node_modules\
|             |- public\
|             |- src\
|             |- static\
|
|- C#BackEnd\
|
\_ .gitignore
```

The contents of the`JSFrontEnd` folder is a standard Gatsby/Netlify project structure, it's just not in the repo root.

Netlify doesn't seem to like this - it wants to run `gatsby build` on the repo root, but of course that isn't going to work - `gatsby` doesn't know what to do because there isn't a `package.json`.

**How do I go about telling Gatsby/Netlify how to use this repo structure?**

My first thoughts on approaches include:

- should I put the package.json in the repo root? If so, how do I tell it that everything's in a sub-folder.
- should I modify the *build* scripts somehow?
- should I be looking to configure Netlify differently when I setup my Netlify site?

Comment: Why don't you just run gatsby from the frontend folder?

Comment: Let me put it this way. Imagine that you weren't using a git repo. What would you do?

Comment: I don't understand the premise of the question. I'm under the impression that Netlify is literally a tool built on top of Git - as far as I understand it doesn't work without a git repo?

Comment: when I'm running gatsby it locally, I DO just run in the sub-folder (similarly, I open VSCode from the sub-folder). This question is specifically about the Netlify hosting integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`netlify.toml`](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#deploy-contexts) file to specify your build settings. In your case, try:

```toml
# Global settings applied to the whole site.  
# 
# “publish” is the directory to publish (relative to root of your repo),
# “command” is your build command,
# “base” is directory to change to before starting build. if you set base:
#    that is where we will look for package.json/.nvmrc/etc not repo root!

[build]
  base    = "JSFrontEnd"
  publish = "JSFrontEnd/public"
  command = "gatsby build"
```

Comment: Ah hah! That looks perfect. Should I be surprised that the command is `gatsby develop`, not `gatsby build`? I was expecting the latter.

Comment: Sorry, yes it should be `build`!

Comment: Can confirm that my Netlify build is now live :)